# Java & Access ruta dinámica

Tags: java, ms-access

tengo una conexión para una base de datos de access en java, este es el código:

```
package clases;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Conexion {

    Connection cn = null;
    
    Statement st = null;
    
    public Conexion(){
    
        try {
            
            String rutafile = "C:\\pruebabd\\BD.accdb";
            
            String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + rutafile;
            
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            
            st = cn.createStatement();
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido conectar con la base de datos: " + e);
            
            System.err.println("Error al conectar con la base de datos: " + e);
            
        }
    
    }
    
    public Connection getConnection(){
    
        return cn;
        
    }
    
    public void Desconexion(){
    
        try {
            
            cn.close();
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            
            Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            System.err.println("Error al cerrar la base de datos: "+ e);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerrar la conexion con la abse de datos.");
            
        }
    
    }
    
}
```

Lo que necesito lograr es una ruta genérica que me funcione en cualquier equipo, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que me ayuden con esto, que el se pueda ejecutar la aplicación desde cualquier otro equipo en cualquier directorio, quiero lograr la conexión con la base de datos con la única condición de que la base de datos .accdb este en el mismo directorio juno al .jar, como puedo lograr eso?.

he modificado las rutas:

`String rutafile = "C:\\pruebabd\\BD.accdb";`

`String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + rutafile;`

Sin lograr lo que deseo de momento.

Me gustaría lograr algo como lo siguiente de ejemplo, con este vídeo:

`File file = new File("src/media/video.mp4");`

En ese caso, siempre y cuando la carpeta src este junto al .jar se logra ejecutar ese vídeo, me gustaría lograr lo mismo con la base de datos.

Muchas gracias de antemano agradecido con cualquier ayuda que me puedan prestar!.

Comment: El objeto Access tiene una propiedad que devuelve la ruta a la base de datos actualmente abierta, es `CurrentProject.Path` Lo que no sé es si puedes usarla de alguna manera en Java, ya que no conozco nada de ese lenguaje. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.currentproject.path

Comment: Estuve revisando eso y aun no lo consigo

Comment: ¿Si guardas el .jar como dices junto al .accdb, no puedes poner 
String rutafile = "BD.accdb";
y ya está?